# Oracle get last inserted row id using OCCI and C++

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

Given the code above, how can I grab the ID of the row inserted into database. I´m using C++ and oracle OCCI interface:

```
    std::stringstream sqlStream("");
    sqlStream << "INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3) RETURNING ID INTO :my_id_param";
    std::string sql(sqlStream.str());
    std::cout << sql << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<oracle::occi::Statement> stmt(connection->createStatement());
    stmt->execute(sql.c_str());

    //??? How can I access here the my_id_param ?
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You are not inserting values into an `ID` column. How are you generating the value to return (or are you expecting a `NULL` value)?

Comment: ID is a TRIGGER that generates values from an  SEQUENCE: `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER MYTRIGGER
       BEFORE INSERT ON MYTABLE
      FOR EACH ROW
      BEGIN
    SELECT MYSEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM DUAL;
      END MYTRIG;'`. Works fine - for every INSERT the ID is automatically generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous PL/SQL and register an OUT parameter to capture the resulting ID. This works with a sequence directly, I've not tried with a sequence used in a trigger.

```
std::stringstream sqlStream("");
sqlStream << "BEGIN INSERT INTO MYTABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (1, 2, 3) RETURNING ID INTO :1; END;";
std::string sql(sqlStream.str());
std::cout << sql << std::endl;

std::unique_ptr<oracle::occi::Statement> stmt(connection->createStatement(sql.c_str()));
stmt->registerOutParam(1, oracle::occi::OCCIINT);
stmt->executeUpdate();
int id = stmt->get(1);
// Use id...
```